# Getting coordinates from Click on a dynamic button with "Point"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Here i'm creating a 10x10 field of buttons for a battleships game. With the Point, which I have decleared on public before, I want to take the X and Y frpom a click on one. Later when I click on a Button i'm opening the Event Handler and show the positions with a MessageBox.

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
            {   
                for (int y = 1; y <= 10; y++)
                {

                    Feld_E[x, y] = new Button
                    {
                        Location = new Point(FeldB, FeldH),
                        Size = new Size(24, 24),
                        TabStop = false,
                        Tag = 1

                    };


                    this.Controls.Add(Feld_E[x, y]);
                    Position.X = x;
                    Position.Y = y;
                    Feld_E[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(Feld_E_Click);  // For the later MessageBox                  

                    FeldH += 0;
                    FeldB += 25;

                    if (y == 10)
                    {
                        k += 25;
                        FeldH = 50 + k;
                        FeldB = 50;
                    }


                }
            }
```

With the Event Handler later;

```
MessageBox.Show(Position.ToString());
```

Output: X=10;Y=10. On a click on X=4;Y=6. Not that what I want

Comment: Position(X, Y) is always overwritten, it will always hold the last assigned value (and it's not clear how `Position` should relate to a specific Button. You Buttons `Tag` property could contain a Class object that defines these details, not just `1`). I suggest: 1) Use a TableLayoutPanel and add your Buttons to its `Controls` Collection. Set the Button's Column and Row explicitly. To read the Button's position on the grid, use the TLP's `GetPositionFromControl()` method. [...]

Comment: [...] 2) Build a grid drawing Rectangles on a surface: use a Class object to hold each Cell's details (the Rectangle that defines it, Border size and Color, status - hit or not, if it contains a ship, which part of the ship). When you click on the grid, loop the `List<class>` and use the `Rectangle.Contains(Point)` method to determine which Cell on the grid was clicked. You can then use Graphics objects (Bitmaps) to represent the ships.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it and hope it works @Jimi